# How can one play every music in a folder 2 times (or a specific number of times)

Tags: music-player, media-player

I have a lot of music files (such as mp3) in a folder.

I am looking for a way to play every file 2 times (or a specific number of times) then going to the next file and playing it 2 times, and so on.

Motivation: When listening to short length educational musics (for example for language learning), listening to the music two times greatly improve understanding of the topic. The ability to automatically play every files 2 times would be really helpful, especially when playing during driving in a car.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd say that's easy, just create a "playlist", but it seems to not be as straight forward as it once was.

Most ways to create a playlist require the installation of an app, but there are other ways to do it too that can make things complicated for a novice user.

One way seems to be to install [VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vlc%20media%20player&c=apps&hl=en&gl=US), browse to the files you want on the playlist, then click on the 3 dots on each file and add to playlist. I would presume that if you add an individual file to the playlist more once it would therefore play as many times as you've added to the playlist.